# Binding Tooltip to Content of Textblock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, tooltip

I have a basic `TextBlock`

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" Text="textOfThisTextblock" ToolTip="..."/>
```

and I want to set the `Tooltip` to the exact same string as the `Text` of the `TextBlock`. How can I do that **automatically**?
So I don't wanna set it manually if I change the `Text`.

I tried

```
ToolTip="{Binding Path=myTextBlock.Text}"
```

but this didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use RelativeSource Self

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" 
           Text="textOfThisTextblock" 
           ToolTip="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"/>
```

or ElementName

```
<TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" 
           Text="textOfThisTextblock" 
           ToolTip="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=myTextBlock}"/>
```

or you can do it for all TextBlocks using Style:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
   <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
           Value="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" />
</Style>
```